# Creating File Watchers in VSCode

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-code, file-watcher, vscode-tasks

I am trying to move away from `WebStorm` and trying to configure `VS Code` to get few functionalities of `WebStorm`. I am trying to implement `File Watcher` functionality in VS Code. 
I used to have File Watchers for Jade and Stylus in WebStorm. I already have gulp tasks for them and have added them in `tasks.json` as well. I have even provided keybindings for them too. But I have to run them manually. What I want is, whenever a file is saved, it checks whether it is a `Jade` file or a `Stylus` file and then run the appropriate task to generate either HTML or CSS file.

Is it possible to do it in VS Code yet? If yes, then how can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must create an extension to accomplish your scenario. You said you already have `gulp` and `task.json` with your automation, so I think it would be relatively easy to translate that to an extension.

You should take care with this points when creating your extension

#### package.json

You extension should work for `Jade` or `Stylus`, so the `package.json` file should have:

```
"activationEvents": [
    "onLanguage:Jade",
    "onLanguage:Stylus"
]
```

#### OnSave Event

There are two events that you could use to detect file saving: `onDidSaveTextDocument` or `onWillSaveTextDocument`, depending on your needs.

#### FileWatcher

VSCode has a built in `FileWatcher`, you just have to create it via `vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher`. The point is that it just monitors *files within the opened folder/project*.

If you need to detect changes *outside*, you should use `fs.watchFile` or `chokidar`.

#### Publishing/Installing

Don't worry if you think your extension *only works for you* or *you can't publish on marketplace*, for any reason, because you can create your own extensions, package them and [install locally](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/publish-extension#_packaging-extensions).